# Python - ValueError: Found array with 0 sample(s) (scale function)

Tags: python, arrays, dataframe, google-colaboratory

I've been trying to fix one mistake for a long time.

The problem can be fixed by deleting the first (possibly the first two) rows of the dataframe (I think so). Btw. I'm working in the Google Colab ..x

Anyone know how to fix the problem?

```
def preprocess_df(df):
    df = df.drop("future", 1) 

    for col in df.columns:  
        if col != "target":  
            df[col] = df[col].pct_change()  
            df.dropna(inplace=True)
            df[col] = preprocessing.scale(df[col].values) 
    df.dropna(inplace=True)
```

...

```
main_df = pd.DataFrame() 

ratios = ["EURCZK=X"]
for ratio in ratios:
    dataset = f'EURCZK=X/{ratio}.csv'
    df = pd.read_csv('EURCZK=X.csv', names=['Date', 'High', 'Low', 'Open', 'Close', 'Volume', 'Adj Close'], skiprows=2) 
    
    df.rename(columns={"close": f"{ratio}_close", "volume": f"{ratio}_volume"}, inplace=True)
    
    df.set_index("Date", inplace=True)
    df = df[[f"Close", f"Volume"]]  

    if len(main_df)==0:  
        main_df = df  
    else:  
        main_df = main_df.join(df)

main_df.fillna(method="ffill", inplace=True) 
main_df.dropna(inplace=True)
#print(main_df.head())  
main_df['future'] = main_df[f'{RATIO_TO_PREDICT}'].shift(-FUTURE_PERIOD_PREDICT)
main_df['target'] = list(map(classify, main_df[f'Close'], main_df['future']))

main_df.dropna(inplace=True)
#print(main_df.tail(10)) 

Date = sorted(main_df.index.values)
last_5pct = sorted(main_df.index.values)[-int(0.05*len(Date))]  

validation_main_df = main_df[(main_df.index >= last_5pct)]  
main_df = main_df[(main_df.index < last_5pct)]  

print(preprocess_df)
print(df.head)

imputer = imputer(missing_values="NaN", strategy="mean", axis=0)
train_x, train_y = preprocess_df(main_df)
validation_x, validation_y = preprocess_df(validation_main_df) #Preprocess dat

#print(f"train data: {len(train_x)} validation: {len(validation_x)}")
#print(f"Dont buys: {train_y.count(0)}, buys: {train_y.count(1)}")
#print(f"VALIDATION Dont buys: {validation_y.count(0)}, buys: {validation_y.count(1)}")
```

And the output is:

```
<function preprocess_df at 0x7fc2568ceb70>
<bound method NDFrame.head of                 Close  Volume     future  target
Date                                            
2003-12-02  32.337502     0.0  32.580002       1
2003-12-03  32.410000     0.0  32.349998       0
2003-12-04  32.580002     0.0  32.020000       0
2003-12-05  32.349998     0.0  32.060001       0
2003-12-08  32.020000     0.0  32.099998       1
...               ...     ...        ...     ...
2020-07-28  26.263800     0.0  26.212500       0
2020-07-29  26.196301     0.0  26.238400       1
2020-07-30  26.212500     0.0  26.258400       1
2020-08-02  26.238400     0.0  26.105101       0
2020-08-03  26.258400     0.0  26.228500       0

[4302 rows x 4 columns]>
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-10-49204f0a12cf> in <module>()
     80 
     81 #imputer = imputer(missing_values="NaN", strategy="mean", axis=0)
---> 82 train_x, train_y = preprocess_df(main_df)
     83 validation_x, validation_y = preprocess_df(validation_main_df)
     84 

2 frames
<ipython-input-10-49204f0a12cf> in preprocess_df(df)
     28             df[col] = df[col].pct_change() 
     29             df.dropna(inplace=True) 
---> 30             df[col] = preprocessing.scale(df[col].values) 
     31 
     32     df.dropna(inplace=True)

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/sklearn/preprocessing/_data.py in scale(X, axis, with_mean, with_std, copy)
    140     X = check_array(X, accept_sparse='csc', copy=copy, ensure_2d=False,
    141                     estimator='the scale function', dtype=FLOAT_DTYPES,
--> 142                     force_all_finite='allow-nan')
    143     if sparse.issparse(X):
    144         if with_mean:

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py in check_array(array, accept_sparse, accept_large_sparse, dtype, order, copy, force_all_finite, ensure_2d, allow_nd, ensure_min_samples, ensure_min_features, warn_on_dtype, estimator)
    584                              " minimum of %d is required%s."
    585                              % (n_samples, array.shape, ensure_min_samples,
--> 586                                 context))
    587 
    588     if ensure_min_features > 0 and array.ndim == 2:

ValueError: Found array with 0 sample(s) (shape=(0,)) while a minimum of 1 is required by the scale function.
```

When I remove '#' on line 84 ("imputer = imputer(missing_values="NaN", strategy="mean", axis=0)"), the answer is returned: **'name' imputer 'is not defined'**. The probles is, i don't know how to define this 'Imputer' ..

Comment: It looks to me like ```imputer``` might be from ```sklearn``` https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.impute.SimpleImputer.html, then again, it doesn't look like ```sklearn.imputer``` has an ```axis``` argument.

Comment: Actually, this ```imputer``` does have an ```axis``` argument: https://scikit-learn.org/0.16/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.Imputer.html

Answer (score 1):

Like Joe said above, based on the arguments handed to the `imputer` call, I'd guess it's an instantiation of this scikit-learn class:

https://scikit-learn.org/0.16/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.Imputer.html

This class has now been replaced as of scikit-learn version 0.20 with the `SimpleImputer` class that Joe also found:

https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.impute.SimpleImputer.html

So, if you got this code from somewhere else, the other source probably had an import of the old `preprocessing.Imputer` class as lowercase `imputer`. You could probably do the same by adding `import sklearn.preprocessing.Imputer as imputer` to the top of your code, assuming you're using sklearn version <=0.20. However, the instantiation doesn't seem to be used for anything in the above code; `fit` is never called on it, so I would think commenting it out where you did wouldn't cause an issue. (Again, I'm basing this only on the shared code.)

Instead, what I'd suggest is that you pay attention to the contents of your `main_df` file by the time it gets handed to the `preprocess` method. There is some column (a `pandas.Series`) in that data which, by the time it's gone through the `pct_change` and `dropna` transformations, has no values remaining in it, and that's what's causing the `scale` function to shrug its shoulders.

Comment: but i don't understand what the problem is with my main_df ..
The error 'ValueError: Found array with 0 sample (s)' persists

Comment: Are you checking columns of `main_df` to make sure none of them are completely empty? If you run `main_df.isna().mean(axis=1)`, look for a column label with a value of 1. My best guess is, that's the problem. Something needs to be in that column.